# Remove answer dimming on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't downvoted answers on meta be non-transparent instead of semi-transparent?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142628/shouldnt-downvoted-answers-on-meta-be-non-transparent-instead-of-semi-transpare)

I think it would be a good idea to either remove answer dimming or increase the threshold at which an answer is dimmed for META (not SO, I think it is absolutely necessary to dim low score answers on SO).  Answers on Meta with negative votes are just as significant as those with 150 upvotes, and  usually are not bad nor incorrect, just unpopular.
This may even help newer meta'ers to understand that votes on meta work different then on SO.

Comment: Ah, so there was an earlier Meta question on this after all, sorry @chown.

Comment: Definitely related but I wouldn't say it's a duplicate; that question was simply asking to remove the dimming entirely, while this question also suggests decreasing the threshold.  (Decreasing the threshold was mentioned in the comments on the other question, but not in the question itself, so I'd say this isn't *quite* a duplicate).

Comment: @WendiKidd: It's still a duplicate. Changing the threshold is a perfectly valid dev response to that question, if they choose to take that path. We don't need two questions saying the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps the title of this question should be changed to "Lower the threshold of dimming downvoted answers on Meta" so as not to conflict with the other question

Comment: the dimming threshold is in fact lower on metas. As I recall it's about -8.