# Should we drop the coloring of opinions in Meta?

Tags: discussion, answers, user-interface, down-votes

Currently, like in Stack Overflow when an answer in meta gets a lot of downvotes it gets greyed out. This makes answers harder to read.

[image]

While the motivation for this is clear in Stack Overflow I'm not sure what purpose of it in Meta is, since upvotes and downvotes do no represent effort and usefulness but agreement or disagreement with the opinion stated.

**Why** is this visual cue in place in meta. **Is it useful?** and **should we drop it?**

(I'm providing my own opinion but obviously - this being meta and all - I'm very interested in ideas)