# Un-fade low-score answers on click/tap too

Tags: feature-request, answers, design, accessibility, touch-screen

Since a couple of weeks ago, [answers that are shown grayed out can be un-faded by hovering the mouse over them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129593/un-fade-low-score-answers-on-rollover-or-click)  This is great especially for users with poor eyesight, who can now read such answers much easier if they want to.

However, hovering works very poorly (if at all) on touch devices, and keeping the cursor constantly hovering over the answer can sometimes be inconvenient on traditional desktops too.

A simple improvement would be to let clicking (or tapping) on the answer body toggle the fading behavior.  **I'm requesting that this feature be implemented.**

One way to do this would be to use the following JS and CSS code (from [my answer to the earlier feature-req](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129593/un-fade-low-score-answers-on-rollover-or-click/216141#216141)):

```js
$('#answers').on( 'click', '.answer.downvoted-answer .post-text', function () {
    $(this).closest('.answer').toggleClass('clicked');
} );
```

```css
.downvoted-answer.clicked .post-text,
.downvoted-answer.clicked .post-signature,
.downvoted-answer.clicked .comments,
.downvoted-answer.clicked .vote > * { opacity: 1 }
```

---

Update: Actually, it turns out that the code above doesn't work properly on all SE sites, since a few sites (like [RPG.SE](http://rpg.stackexchange.com)) still have oddball styling that doesn't use `opacity` for downvoted posts.  (This might be considered a bug, or at least a design wart, in itself.)  Anyway, the code that I've added as a client-side workaround into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.32 looks like this:

```js
$('#answers').on( 'click', '.answer.downvoted-answer .post-text', function () {
    $(this).closest('.answer').addClass('downvoted-answer-clicked').removeClass('downvoted-answer');
} ).on( 'click', '.answer.downvoted-answer-clicked .post-text', function () {
    $(this).closest('.answer').addClass('downvoted-answer').removeClass('downvoted-answer-clicked');
} );
```

Yeah, this is kind of ugly, but it ensures that the code works regardless of how downvoted answers are styled on any particular SE site.

Comment: This is probably a legal requirement in places such as the UK which have laws against digital disability discrimination. :)

Comment: Not sure I agree with the proposed solution but I definitely agree with the need for one.

Comment: It appears this has been implemented.